# I have a problem in multiplication with R

Tags: r

I have some calculation and I realized that I had a problem on the kind

```
111111111 * 111111111
```

I don't have the correct result, even when I use the bit64 library

Comment: Looks OK to me ` as.integer64(111111111) * as.integer64(111111111)`
[1] 12345678987654321     What do you think you should get?

Comment: Can you give the *exact* code you used?  For example, loading the `bit64` package (`library("bit64")` doesn't do anything by itself; you need to use `as.integer64()` as suggested by @G5W ...

Answer (score 0):

Also check out FAQ 7.31 so that you get an understanding of floating point numbers and the precision you can get.